# Is it possible to insert data in to Elastic Search from URL?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

Currently, Im working on `ElasticSearch` and I was able to insert data into ElasticSearch using CMD is there a way that I can insert the JSON data from web URL to ELasticSerach Using java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use rest client. Following is the code -

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
       new HttpHost(hostname, portnumber, "http")).build();
```

Otherwise, you can use regular transport client

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hostName), portNumber));
```